# How to insert data on Google Tag Manager's dataLayer using wpForms wpforms_process_complete on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I want to push an event to Google Tag Manager's dataLayer when the user submitted the form successfully using wpForms plugin. I tried using the wpForms hook "wpforms_process_complete" and it seems that it's not working.

Sample code in functions.php:

```
function wpf_process_completed( $fields, $entry, $form_id, $form_data ) {
  if ($form_data['id'] === 1033) {
        ?>
            <script>
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                window.dataLayer.push({ event: 'wpFormsSubmitted' });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'wpf_process_completed', 10, 4);
```

But nothing happens.

I also tried printing a string and resulted an error.

```
function wpf_process_completed( $fields, $entry, $form_id, $form_data ) {
  echo 'submitted';
}

Error:
WPForms AJAX submit error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
```

I don't know how to make it work. Please help!

Comment: Why do you need to data layer push, you can track the thank you url or thank you banner?

Comment: I tried tracking the thank you url but for some instance, it doesn't work, the tags didn't triggered.

Comment: Can you post the set up of the trigger for us to review?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.dataLayer.push({ "event": "wpFormsSubmitted" });
```

Valid JSON string should have double quotes

Comment: Still not working. I'll try tracking the success message. Thank you again @ASomN for the answer!